# Import System time without time zone in R

Tags: r

How do you get system time without timezone?
I'm currently using

```
> x<-Sys.time()
> x
[1] "2015-12-09 10:37:50 MYT"
```

But I wouldn't need the `"MYT"` part which is the time zone.

Comment: `format(Sys.time(), tz="")`?

Comment: `format(x,usetz=FALSE)` courtesy of `?format.POSIXct`

Comment: @thelatemail Even better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to do that. I would recommend formatting the date like that:

`format(Sys.time(), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')`